# jasmine karma @viewChild to open the model shows this.$modal.modal is not a function in angular 5

Tags: unit-testing, angular5, karma-jasmine

I am new to jasmine karma test cases, when I called the openMail method from spec file it shows this.$modal.modal is not a function errors.
can anyone help me to solve this issues

**MY spec file**

```
it('should call openMail ', () => {
    component.openMail();
    spyOn(component, 'openMail');
    expect(component.openMail).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

**component.ts file**

```
 @ViewChild('addmail')
  AddMailModel: ModalComponent;

 openMail() {
    this.data.mail = '';
    this.AddMailModel.open();
  }
```